# Django run code once on every successful login

Tags: python, django, authentication

How do I run a piece of code on django after a successful user login? I cannot put the code in the view that is shown after login for the following reasing:

- The redirect is dynamic, so the view after login differs. It depends
  on the page the user tried to access.
- I want to run my code only once, only right after the moment a user logs in.

I am looking for the most simple pythonic way to do this? Is it possible without writing my own authentication middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't put it in the view that processes the login itself. You've certainly written something that takes the output from the username/password form and calls auth.login(), so that would seem to be the right place to do it.

Alternatively, you could write a signal listener for the [`user_logged_in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#topics-auth-signals) signal.

Comment: I use the standard Django view: django.contrib.auth.views.login, so I haven't written any login handling myself. I am now looking into django signal listeners.

Comment: The signal listener is indeed the way to go.